# Looking for advice on getting events to work

Tags: c#, events

I'm looking for some help in understanding Events.  I've been reading articles on them and watching tutorial videos.

I almost understand them, but I keep hitting snags.

I made myself a simple WinForms test app to try and learn the process.  In the app, there are 2 walking sprites running around the screen.
When you click on the form, it creates a sprite of a falling thwomp (And it creates an event) the walker sprites should react to the event by choosing a new walking path headed away from the sprite.  I think I've written everything correctly, but when I compile it I get the error:

> Error  1   Inconsistent accessibility: parameter type 'eventStomper.RunEventArgs' is less accessible than delegate 'eventStomper.RunInFear'
>   Error   2   Inconsistent accessibility: parameter type 'eventStomper.RunEventArgs' is less accessible than method 'eventStomper.Walker.RunAway(object, eventStomper.RunEventArgs)'

I'm at a loss because everything is public.  Any suggestions on there error?  And, any advice on Event handling?

Here's the source code boiled down to just the relevant bits:

```
namespace eventStomper
{

    public delegate void RunInFear(object sender, RunEventArgs re); //The delegate for responding to events.

    public partial class Form1 : Form
    {
        public Form1()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
            spawnWalkers();  //Create a couple of walkers to roam around the form  

        }
        List<Thwomp> thowmpList = new List<Thwomp>(); //List of thwomps.  This is iterated through for animation.
        List<Walker> walkerList = new List<Walker>();// Same thing with the walkers.

        public void pictureBox1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e) //When you click on the background, it spawns a thwomp
        {
            Point _spawnPoint = this.PointToClient(Cursor.Position);


            Thwomp _thwomp = new Thwomp(_spawnPoint,  sprite );  //Generate a new Thwomp
            thowmpList.Add(_thwomp); //Add it to the list of Thwomps
            _thwomp.TimeToRun += walkerList[0].RunAway; //Register with the two walkers roaming around.
            _thwomp.TimeToRun += walkerList[1].RunAway;

            //Do other things to setup the thwomp sprite

        }


    }

   public class Thwomp
    {
        public int spriteX = 0;//Current sprite location
        public int spriteY = 0;
        public int targetX = 0;//Where the thwomp will land.
        public int targetY = 0;


        public event RunInFear TimeToRun;

      public void Animate()
        {
            //Do Animation steps.
        }
        public Thwomp(Point spawnPoint,  PictureBox spriteIncoming)
        {
            RunEventArgs re = new RunEventArgs();
            re._pointOfFear = spawnPoint;

            //Setup thwomp sprite 
            TimeToRun(this, re); //Trigger the event.
        }
    }

    public class Walker
    {
        public int spriteX = 0;  //Current sprite location
        public int spriteY = 0;

        public Walker(Point spawnPoint, PictureBox spriteIncoming)
        {
                //Create the walker 
        }

        public void RunAway(Point dangerPoint)
        {
            if (Math.Abs(sprite.Top - dangerPoint.Y) < 20 && Math.Abs(sprite.Left - dangerPoint.X) < 20) //If near a newly created thwomp, run away.
            {
                 //Pick a path headed away from the danger.  
            }
        }

        public void Animate()
        {
            //Move the walker away.
        }
    }

    class RunEventArgs : EventArgs 
    {
        public Point _pointOfFear;
    }
}
```

Comment: Change this `class RunEventArgs : EventArgs` into `public class RunEventArgs : EventArgs`

Answer (score 5, accepted):

> I'm at a loss because everything is public.

Not quite. As the error message says:

> parameter type 'eventStomper.RunEventArgs' is less accessible than delegate 'eventStomper.RunInFear'

According to that message, `RunEventArgs` is less accessible than `RunInFear`. Therefore, let's look at the accessibility levels of those two types:

```
public delegate void RunInFear(object sender, RunEventArgs re);
```

So, that is public. So far, so good.

```
class RunEventArgs : EventArgs 
{
    public Point _pointOfFear;
}
```

Aha! This one has no accessibility assigned to, which means that - according to the [docs](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ba0a1yw2.aspx) - it will default to `internal`:

> Top-level types, which are not nested in other types, can only have internal or public accessibility. The default accessibility for these types is internal.

Therefore, make that `RunEventArgs` class `public` and your code should compile.

Comment: That takes care of the compile error.  When I click the picture box, it's not triggering.  I'm getting an error "Object reference not set to an instance of an object." because when I try to call the method "TimeToRun(this, re); //Trigger the event." it's saying that TimeToRun is a null object.  Suggestions?